# How to isolate builds in jenkins using docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins 2 on a dedicated server. My build is a multibranch pipeline and the first step of this build is to do a `docker-compose up -d` in order to run databases (redis and mongo) and running tests against them.

Everything works fine until you have 2 commits on different branches at the same time ; one of the 2 build cannot start the container, because the port is of course already taken.

I would love to be able to run the 2 builds on 2 different branches in parallels : how cat I achieve that ?

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:2.6.12
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  mem_limit: 100m

redis:
  image: redis:3.0.7-alpine
  ports:
    - 6379:6379
  mem_limit: 60m
```

My build is done with a `Jenkinsfile` and I have read there is a way to run a build inside a container

```
docker.image("some image").inside{
    // build
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you omit port exposing. Or you need expose docker port to random docker port

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:2.6.12
  ports:
    - 27017
  mem_limit: 100m

redis:
  image: redis:3.0.7-alpine
  ports:
    - 6379
  mem_limit: 60m
```

if your application running into docker network port exposing don`t needed.

Comment: I need to communicate with my containers, so I have to expose some ports I guess

Comment: Do you build your app inside docker container? Or on the host machine?

Comment: on the host machine, but I would like to be able to do it in a container with docker-compose insede